# getBBox error when "use strict"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, strict

When
    `"use strict";`

is active for my D3JS force network graph, I am unable to use `this.getBBox();` to rotate the edge label text in a force network graph using the code:

```
edgelabels.attr('transform',function(d,i){
  if (d.target.x<d.source.x){
    bbox = this.getBBox();
    rx = bbox.x+bbox.width/2;
    ry = bbox.y+bbox.height/2;
    return 'rotate(180 '+rx+' '+ry+')';
  }
  else { return 'rotate(0)'; }
});
```

If I disable `"use strict;"` my code runs without error and the label is rotated correctly.  Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/NovasTaylor/cnaqaxnh/

I based my original code on this block:
http://bl.ocks.org/jhb/5955887

How can my code be fixed to run using `"use strict;"` either with getBBox() or an alternative to getBBox()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is not `getBBox()`, but the lack of `var`: in non-strict mode, the assignment to an undeclared variable considers that variable to be global. However, that won't work in strict mode.

If you look at the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) about strict mode:

> First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create **global variables**. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work" (although future failure is possible: likely, in modern JavaScript). Assignments which would accidentally create global variables instead throw in strict mode. (emphasis mine)

So, instead of:

```
edgelabels.attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
        bbox = this.getBBox();
        rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
        ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
        return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
    } else {
        return 'rotate(0)';
    }
});
```

It should be:

```
edgelabels.attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        var rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
        var ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
        return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
    } else {
        return 'rotate(0)';
    }
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/onnoqyp4/